# Counting subgraph isomorphisms across digraphs

Tags: graph

I have a set of approximately 600 densely connected digraphs consisting of ~ 10 nodes with ~ 30 edges. I'm looking for algorithms that will efficiently count subgraph isomorphisms.

Update: [Gspan](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~xyan/papers/gSpan-short.pdf) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this article can help: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/3192839_A_new_algorithm_for_error-tolerant_subgraph_isomorphism_detection

They do subgraph decomposition and matching. I'm thinking that you could do the decomposition on all your graphs in order to find the most common subgraphs.